# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: jquery-1.10.2.min.js

Tags: jquery

I have a problem when any jQuery code snippet is called I get the following error.

In Firefox :

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 
/plugins/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
Line 4
```

In chrome :

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 
jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4at.error
jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4mt
jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4kt
jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4at
jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4x.fn.extend.find
jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5x.fn.x.init
jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4e.fn.init
jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js:2x
jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4c
bootstrap.min.js:6(anonymous function)
bootstrap.min.js:6x.extend.each
jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4x.fn.x.each
jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4b
bootstrap.min.js:6x.event.dispatch
jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5v.handle
```

Comment: are you calling jQuery before initialization ?

Comment: no i am not doing that, just want to clear that even after error is  there the thing works perfectly on firefox and chrome but on IE-9 sometimes jquery function failed.